react-native bluetooth printing gives error
im working on a simple react-native receipt application.
currently using package : https://github.com/AllInOneYT/react-native-thermal-printer
when i use
await ThermalPrinterModule.printBluetooth({       
         macAddress: 'DC:0D:30:81:8F:39',
         payload :'Hello man go...'  
        }  
      );

it gives error
can not read property printBluetooth of null

in the documentation no other parameter is to be given ref documentation and example. how can i fix this ? seek help.
it gives
